# JSON Object as @RequestBody on Spring 4.16

Tags: java, android, json, spring, spring-mvc

So i have this android application that send jsonObject for a jsonObjectRequest (I'm using volley) with POST method. The JSON file was sent but the server (this is where i'm using Spring btw) is not responding. The code pretty much like these.

Android Code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
      try {
          userToken = response.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
   //  blablabla
```

Server Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth/")
public class AuthController {

String userEmail;
String userPassword;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LoginResponse loginResponse(@RequestBody Auth auth){

    userEmail = auth.getEmail();
    userPassword = auth.getPassword();
// blablabla
```

Auth Object:

```
public class Auth {

    private String email;
    private String password;

// blablabla
```

It seems like the server didn't receive the JsonObject from the android client correctly. (The server is able to send JSON to android client perfectly in another case, though). I'm using spring-4.16, jackson-core, jackson-annotation, jackson-databind (2.2.2). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception ?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you supplied first thing that I suspect can be is that JSONObject doesn't have same field's name with Auth on server.
Also it is possible that `HttpMessageConverter` which is used for mapping objects from request to object in controller is not doing his job correctly.

I would first try to just try to recieve parameters from body, without `Auth` object. If Spring maps it fine than `HttpMessageConverter` is the problem, if it does not than the usage of `@RequestBody`, which I can't be from code you supplied.

Comment: Thanks for the question.. it works fine now.. the problem is the android client didn't send a correct content type. shortly, i miss the getBodyContentType() override..